# Better way to extract phone number and reformat?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Phone number data in various formats (I've chosen these because the data coming in is unreliable and not in expected formats):

```
+1 480-874-4666
404-581-4000
(805) 682-4726
978-851-7321, Ext 2606
413- 658-1100
(513) 287-7000,Toll Free (800) 733-2077
1 (813) 274-8130
212-363-3200,Media Relations: 212-668-2251.
323/221-2164
```

My Ruby code to extract all the digits, remove any leading 1's for the USA country code, then use the first 10 digits to create the "new" phone number in a format desired:

```
  nums = phone_number_string.scan(/[0-9]+/)
  if nums.size > 0
    all_nums = nums.join
    all_nums = all_nums[0..0] == "1" ? all_nums[1..-1] : all_nums
    if all_nums.size >= 10
      ten_nums = all_nums[0..9]
      final_phone = "#{ten_nums[0..2]}-#{ten_nums[3..5]}-#{ten_nums[6..9]}"
    else
      final_phone = ""
    end
    puts "#{final_phone}"
  else
    puts "No number to fix."
  end
```

The results are **very good**!

```
480-874-4666
404-581-4000
805-682-4726
978-851-7321
413-658-1100
513-287-7000
813-274-8130
212-363-3200
323-221-2164
```

**But, I think there's a better way. Can you refactor this to be more efficient, more legible, or more useful?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a much simpler approach using only regexes and substitution:

```
def extract_phone_number(input)
  if input.gsub(/\D/, "").match(/^1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/)
    [$1, $2, $3].join("-")
  end
end
```

This strips all non-digits (`\D`), skips an optional leading one (`^1?`), then extracts the first remaining 10 digits in chunks (`(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})`) and formats.

Here's the test:

```
test_data = {
  "+1 480-874-4666"                             => "480-874-4666",
  "404-581-4000"                                => "404-581-4000",
  "(805) 682-4726"                              => "805-682-4726",
  "978-851-7321, Ext 2606"                      => "978-851-7321",
  "413- 658-1100"                               => "413-658-1100",
  "(513) 287-7000,Toll Free (800) 733-2077"     => "513-287-7000",
  "1 (813) 274-8130"                            => "813-274-8130",
  "212-363-3200,Media Relations: 212-668-2251." => "212-363-3200",
  "323/221-2164"                                => "323-221-2164",
  ""                                            => nil,
  "foobar"                                      => nil,
  "1234567"                                     => nil,
}

test_data.each do |input, expected_output|
  extracted = extract_phone_number(input)
  print "FAIL (expected #{expected_output}): " unless extracted == expected_output
  puts extracted
end
```

Comment: This approach is probably faster.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is a bit different (and I think better IMHO :-): I needed to not miss any phone numbers, even if there were 2 on a line. I also didn't want to get lines that had 3 sets of numbers that were far apart (see the cookies example), and I didn't want to mistake an IP address as a phone number.

Code to allow multiple numbers per line, but also require sets of digits to be 'close' to each other:

```
def extract_phone_number(input)
  result = input.scan(/(\d{3})\D{0,3}(\d{3})\D{0,3}(\d{4})/).map{|e| e.join('-')}
  # <result> is an Array of whatever phone numbers were extracted, and the remapping
  # takes care of cleaning up each number in the Array into a format of 800-432-1234
  result = result.join(' :: ')
  # <result> is now a String, with the numbers separated by ' :: '
  # ... or there is another way to do it (see text below the code) that only gets the
  # first phone number only.

  # Details of the Regular Expressions and what they're doing
  # 1. (\d{3}) -- get 3 digits (and keep them)
  # 2. \D{0,3} -- allow skipping of up to 3 non-digits. This handles hyphens, parentheses, periods, etc.
  # 3. (\d{3}) -- get 3 more digits (and keep them)
  # 4. \D{0,3} -- skip up to 0-3 non-digits
  # 5. (\d{4}) -- keep the final 4 digits

  result.empty? ? nil : result
end
```

And here are the tests (with a few additional tests)

```
test_data = {
  "DB=Sequel('postgres://user:username@192.168.1.101/test_test')" => nil, # DON'T MISTAKE IP ADDRESSES AS PHONE NUMBERS
  "100 cookies + 950 cookes = 1050 cookies"     => nil,  # THIS IS NEW
  "this 123 is a 456 bad number 7890"           => nil,  # THIS IS NEW
  "212-363-3200,Media Relations: 212-668-2251." => "212-363-3200 :: 212-668-2251", # THIS IS CHANGED
  "this is +1 480-874-4666"                     => "480-874-4666",
  "something 404-581-4000"                      => "404-581-4000",
  "other (805) 682-4726"                        => "805-682-4726",
  "978-851-7321, Ext 2606"                      => "978-851-7321",
  "413- 658-1100"                               => "413-658-1100",
  "(513) 287-7000,Toll Free (800) 733-2077"     => "513-287-7000 :: 800-733-2077", # THIS IS CHANGED
  "1 (813) 274-8130"                            => "813-274-8130",
  "323/221-2164"                                => "323-221-2164",
  ""                                            => nil,
  "foobar"                                      => nil,
  "1234567"                                     => nil,
}

def test_it(test_data)
  test_data.each do |input, expected_output|
    extracted = extract_phone_number(input)
    puts "#{extracted == expected_output ? 'good': 'BAD!'}   ::#{input} => #{extracted.inspect}"
  end
end

test_it(test_data)
```

An Alternate implementation: by using "scan" it will automatically apply the regular expression multiple times, which is good if you want to extra more than 1 phone number per line. If you just want to get the first phone number on a line then you could also use:

```
first_phone_number = begin 
  m = /(\d{3})\D{0,3}(\d{3})\D{0,3}(\d{4})/.match(input)
  [m[1],m[2],m[3]].join('-')
rescue nil; end
```

(just a different way of doing things, using the "match" function of RegExp)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, though thought I'd share a solution.

```
def extract_phone_number(input)
  input.delete!('^0-9').gsub!(/^1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '\1-\2-\3')[0..11]
rescue NoMethodError => e
  nil
end
```

`delete!` removes all non-numerical characters.

`gsub!` matches the digits, then templates them into hyphen separated string.

`[0..11]` slices off wanted digits (in case of extensions)

The rescue block protects from modification methods being called on `nil`

Using the tests posted above.

```
tests = {
  '+1 480-874-4666'                             => '480-874-4666',
  '404-581-4000'                                => '404-581-4000',
  '(805) 682-4726'                              => '805-682-4726',
  '978-851-7321, Ext 2606'                      => '978-851-7321',
  '413- 658-1100'                               => '413-658-1100',
  '(513) 287-7000,Toll Free (800) 733-2077'     => '513-287-7000',
  '1 (813) 274-8130'                            => '813-274-8130',
  '212-363-3200,Media Relations: 212-668-2251.' => '212-363-3200',
  '323/221-2164'                                => '323-221-2164',
  ''                                            => nil,
  'foobar'                                      => nil,
  '1234567'                                     => nil
}

tests.each do |input, expected_output|
  input  = input.dup if input.frozen?
  result = extract_phone_number(input)

  if result == expected_output
    print "PASS: #{result}\n"
  else
    print "FAIL (expected #{expected_output})\n"
  end
end

# Console
=> PASS: 480-874-4666
=> PASS: 404-581-4000
=> PASS: 805-682-4726
=> PASS: 978-851-7321
=> PASS: 413-658-1100
=> PASS: 513-287-7000
=> PASS: 813-274-8130
=> PASS: 212-363-3200
=> PASS: 323-221-2164
=> PASS:
=> PASS:
=> PASS:
```

Answer (score 0):

For numbers in the North American plan one could extract the first number using `phone_number_string.gsub(/\D/, '').match(/^1?(\d{10})/)[1]`

For example:

```
test_phone_numbers = ["+1 480-874-4666",
                      "404-581-4000",
                      "(805) 682-4726",
                      "978-851-7321, Ext 2606",
                      "413- 658-1100",
                      "(513) 287-7000,Toll Free (800) 733-2077",
                      "1 (813) 274-8130",
                      "212-363-3200,Media Relations: 212-668-2251.",
                      "323/221-2164",
                      "foobar"]

test_phone_numbers.each do | phone_number_string | 
  match = phone_number_string.gsub(/\D/, '').match(/^1?(\d{10})/)
  puts(
    if (match)
      "#{match[1][0..2]}-#{match[1][3..5]}-#{match[1][6..9]}"
    else
      "No number to fix."
    end
  )
end
```

As with the starting code, this doesn't capture multiple numbers, e.g., "(513) 287-7000,Toll Free (800) 733-2077"

FWIW, I've found it easier in the long run to capture and store complete numbers, i.e., including the country code and no separators; making guesses during the capture on which [numbering plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan) ones missing a prefix are in and selecting formats, e.g., NANP v. DE, when rendering.